# bind and live not working

Tags: jquery

(the input value is filled with 'a' 'links' but after the links are generated (inside another div ) thei do no act on hover)
i have this:

```
<a href="#">This works</a><br><br>

<input class="input" type="text" style="width:400px;" value=" <a href='#'>This works...NOT</a> "/><br>
<div id="test"></div>
```

and this jquery:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#f00');
},function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#000');
});

$(".input").bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#test').html(this.value);
});
```

i tried wit bind and live, but the link created inside a input and copyed to a div - no changes color on hover. Please help

Comment: tx for comment, is this ok? http://jsfiddle.net/psvsq/2/

Comment: @Gina, why aren't you using CSS? It takes some of the headache out of this. See my answer below.

Comment: @NullRef because in the future is not only the color that have to change but other stuffs too like hrefs, title attr, and other, all on mouseover-out / or hover

Comment: @Gina, gottcha, I think you have your answer...you should accept @kei's so they get credit.

Comment: I see the green 'V' ! I will thanks to all!

Comment: thanks! :) I accepted! (I'm scared too. But for now all is working good thanks to you guys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this jquery:

```
$('a').live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    $(this).css('color', '#f00');
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', '#000');
  }
});
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, the live function with, `live("mouseover mouseout"` will switch between `mouseover` and `mouseout` events?

Comment: @Phil Yeah, the first argument has the event types that the element will have. You can even do `("click mouseover mouseout keydown keyup ...` rather than making separate `live`/`bind` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something a little closer to this:

```
$('a').live('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css('color','#f00');
}).live('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).css('color','#000');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/B35mZ/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `a` inside the value of a text box. Hence, its not a real link in the DOM.

Comment: "the links are generated (inside another div)"... Is this relevant? I don't see it in the question, but I guess this is what OP means?

Comment: what can i use? i need a space to be filled with links like: '<a href='...'> link name </a> and this link have to result in other div like: 'link name' and act as jqery told. (change color on hover)

Comment: You need to look more closely at what @Gina is doing. An element is created OUTSIDE the textbox onKeyup

Answer (score 0):

You need the `live` on the `a`'s not the input.

```
$('a').live("hover mouseout",function() {
$(this).css('color', '#f00');
},function(){
$(this).css('color', '#000');
});

$(".input").keyup(function() {
$('#test').html(this.value);
});
```

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NullRef/2mNAy/)

Also I'm curious why you are going to all this trouble and not just using CSS.

[This fiddle works as well](http://jsfiddle.net/NullRef/2mNAy/1/)

with

```
a:hover{
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your question said "no changes color on hover." which this example does but I think you want @kei's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of what Daniel said, but what you can do is this:

Place it in a div:

`$("div").bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#test').html($(this).html());
});`

Comment: But I thought it was because the a shouldn't be in the value of the textbox/input... I don't think that will validate either

Comment: User input is always "valid" in the sense you're thinking of